# Load catel view using ViewModelToViewConverter in xmlnsdefinition

Tags: wpf, mvvm, xml-namespaces, catel

Currently we have a WPF userControl Library where the namespaces are mapped to an XML Namespace using the

```
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition]
```

statement.
When we try to use controls out of this library in a WPF Application that references this assembly, using a ContentPresenter

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentContent, Converter={StaticResource ViewModelToViewConverter}}" />
```

we always get a

```
System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException("Type reference cannot find type named '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation}XYZView")
```

What are we doing wrong - or is catel not designed to show controls using the ViewModelToViewConverter if they are in a XmlnsDefinition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, fixed - the error was on another place in the source... Catel definitely works also when using Xmlnsdefinitions.